# VB.NET UserControl inherits from AutoScaleDimensions

Tags: vb.net

I just added the

```
Public Class ucGrid : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control
```

to

```
Public Class ucGrid
```

and then I get an error on the following 2 lines:

```
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
```

The errors I am getting are ".AutoScaleDimnension" is not a member of uGridGrid" and "AutoScaleMode is not a member of uGrid"

Can somebody tell me what is going on here? I guess I am missing extensions but I don't really know where  / how to fix this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: do you need both of them or are you just puzzled?

Comment: @Plutonix I am just puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoScaleMode` is a member of Forms,  `AutoScaleDimensions` is a member of Container control.  When your thing was a `UserControl` (guessing from the name `ucGrid`), it was a member of `Forms` and inherited from `ContainerControl` so both properties were available.

Now since you inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` (which inherits from  `Component`), those properties are not there.  Technically, `ucGrid` is no longer a UserControl, but a control.

Comment: But when I comment those 2 lines, I get the error "        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.tws.frmMain
        End Sub. The error is "System.ArgumentException: Invalid parameter: " & vbCrLf & " at System.Drawing.Bitmap" (...)

Comment: some designer code will have been invalidated when your thing changed from a UserControl to a Control.  You should just be able to delete the design instance, save and readd it

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but at least I guess it will help over people as well. May I ask you where this code might be located? I searched for "ucGrid" in the "frmMain.Designer.vb" file, and it was not there.

Comment: `OnCreateMainForm` will reside in the Application.Designer.vb file.  Turn on Show All files and look under MyProject.  You should also be able to drill to it from the error locus.

Comment: The error was an "internal one" in the ucGrid control. At initialization, I created a buffer bitmap to hold some graphics. This bitmap was created from Me.Width, Me.Height (Me=The usercontrol). For some reason, width and height were 0. I put that buffer bitmap creation stuff into the resize event where it should belong, and it works now. Thank you for this great lesson!